# How do I set Notepad++ as the default editor?

Tags: windows-7, windows, notepad++, file-association

I want set Notepad++ as the default editor. I tried to set it by right-clicking on a file, then Open With. But I did not see Notepad++ in the resulting list (even after clicking on Choose Other Programs).

When I try to redirect to Notepad++ through the Browse option to `notepad++.exe` file it is doing nothing. (Its not recognizing somehow)

[image]

Answer (score 106, accepted):

1. Start Notepad++ with elevated privileges.

   [image]
2. In Notepad++, go to **Settings**, **Preferences...**
3. Go to the **File Association** tab.
4. Select **fortran,TeX,SQL** and then **`.sql`** and add it to the registered extensions:

   [image]
5. Click **Close**.

Comment: The key here is that Notepad++ *must* be run as administrator (elevated privileges), otherwise the file association's will not "stick".

Comment: Did that in my Windows 8 computer. It took just fine as admin, but the associations made there do not matter much since it doesn't make a difference for my user account, which does not have those preferences saved. This app sucks on Windows 8.

Comment: Did not work for me with the today installed 6.7.9.2 version of Notepad++. I'm stuck, and it worked with previous versions... Any idea ?

Comment: Shame this doesn't explain *why* Windows(7?) behaves like this.

Comment: Doesn't work for me either. I even went and reg-edited the txt extention to open with notepad++ and it got a "unknown program" icon and asked me what program to open it with. Worse, the open with menu refuses to allow me to use notepad++ even if I browse to it!

Comment: After following above steps, additionally, I had to associate Notepad to the file type using Open With (now Notepad++ showed up in the list). Then the file's icons changed and double clicking it opened it in Notepad++. Way too complicated, for no reason...
Found clear workaround steps here: https://github.com/notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plus/issues/2454

Answer (score 9):

Start notepad++ as administrator, by right-clicking it's icon and selecting the relevant action:

[image]

In `Settings > Preferences...`, you can associate the extensions you want with Notepad++, using this dialog:

[image: notepad++ association dialog]

In this case, clicking on the red-outlined arrow would assicoate all .txt with Notepad++.

Answer (score 9):

You can modify the registry. [From this website](http://techexplored.com/replace-notepad-notepad-windows/), I found a pretty thorough regedit modification that works fine for me and really changes the default right click "Edit" program.

The hex portions are just the same path string to Notepad++, I don't know why those were put in hex, but it is harmless. Again, I didn't create this code.

1. Copy the following text and paste it in a new .txt and save it
2. Rename it to filename.reg.
3. And then just double-click it and accept the pop ups that warn you about modifying the registry.

---

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\batfile\shell\edit\command]
@=hex(2):22,00,43,00,3a,00,5c,00,50,00,72,00,6f,00,67,00,72,00,61,00,6d,00,20,\
00,46,00,69,00,6c,00,65,00,73,00,20,00,28,00,78,00,38,00,36,00,29,00,5c,00,\
4e,00,6f,00,74,00,65,00,70,00,61,00,64,00,2b,00,2b,00,5c,00,6e,00,6f,00,74,\
00,65,00,70,00,61,00,64,00,2b,00,2b,00,2e,00,65,00,78,00,65,00,22,00,20,00,\
22,00,25,00,31,00,22,00,00,00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\batfile\shell\print\command]
@=hex(2):22,00,43,00,3a,00,5c,00,50,00,72,00,6f,00,67,00,72,00,61,00,6d,00,20,\
00,46,00,69,00,6c,00,65,00,73,00,20,00,28,00,78,00,38,00,36,00,29,00,5c,00,\
4e,00,6f,00,74,00,65,00,70,00,61,00,64,00,2b,00,2b,00,5c,00,6e,00,6f,00,74,\
00,65,00,70,00,61,00,64,00,2b,00,2b,00,2e,00,65,00,78,00,65,00,22,00,20,00,\
2f,00,70,00,20,00,22,00,25,00,31,00,22,00,00,00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\cmdfile\shell\edit\command]
@=hex(2):22,00,43,00,3a,00,5c,00,50,00,72,00,6f,00,67,00,72,00,61,00,6d,00,20,\
00,46,00,69,00,6c,00,65,00,73,00,20,00,28,00,78,00,38,00,36,00,29,00,5c,00,\
4e,00,6f,00,74,00,65,00,70,00,61,00,64,00,2b,00,2b,00,5c,00,6e,00,6f,00,74,\
00,65,00,70,00,61,00,64,00,2b,00,2b,00,2e,00,65,00,78,00,65,00,22,00,20,00,\
22,00,25,00,31,00,22,00,00,00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\cmdfile\shell\print\command]
@=hex(2):22,00,43,00,3a,00,5c,00,50,00,72,00,6f,00,67,00,72,00,61,00,6d,00,20,\
00,46,00,69,00,6c,00,65,00,73,00,20,00,28,00,78,00,38,00,36,00,29,00,5c,00,\
4e,00,6f,00,74,00,65,00,70,00,61,00,64,00,2b,00,2b,00,5c,00,6e,00,6f,00,74,\
00,65,00,70,00,61,00,64,00,2b,00,2b,00,2e,00,65,00,78,00,65,00,22,00,20,00,\
2f,00,70,00,20,00,22,00,25,00,31,00,22,00,00,00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\inffile\shell\open\command]
@=hex(2):22,00,43,00,3a,00,5c,00,50,00,72,00,6f,00,67,00,72,00,61,00,6d,00,20,\
00,46,00,69,00,6c,00,65,00,73,00,20,00,28,00,78,00,38,00,36,00,29,00,5c,00,\
4e,00,6f,00,74,00,65,00,70,00,61,00,64,00,2b,00,2b,00,5c,00,6e,00,6f,00,74,\
00,65,00,70,00,61,00,64,00,2b,00,2b,00,2e,00,65,00,78,00,65,00,22,00,20,00,\
22,00,25,00,31,00,22,00,00,00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\inffile\shell\print\command]
@=hex(2):22,00,43,00,3a,00,5c,00,50,00,72,00,6f,00,67,00,72,00,61,00,6d,00,20,\
00,46,00,69,00,6c,00,65,00,73,00,20,00,28,00,78,00,38,00,36,00,29,00,5c,00,\
4e,00,6f,00,74,00,65,00,70,00,61,00,64,00,2b,00,2b,00,5c,00,6e,00,6f,00,74,\
00,65,00,70,00,61,00,64,00,2b,00,2b,00,2e,00,65,00,78,00,65,00,22,00,20,00,\
2f,00,70,00,20,00,22,00,25,00,31,00,22,00,00,00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\inifile\shell\open\command]
@=hex(2):22,00,43,00,3a,00,5c,00,50,00,72,00,6f,00,67,00,72,00,61,00,6d,00,20,\
00,46,00,69,00,6c,00,65,00,73,00,20,00,28,00,78,00,38,00,36,00,29,00,5c,00,\
4e,00,6f,00,74,00,65,00,70,00,61,00,64,00,2b,00,2b,00,5c,00,6e,00,6f,00,74,\
00,65,00,70,00,61,00,64,00,2b,00,2b,00,2e,00,65,00,78,00,65,00,22,00,20,00,\
22,00,25,00,31,00,22,00,00,00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\inifile\shell\print\command]
@=hex(2):22,00,43,00,3a,00,5c,00,50,00,72,00,6f,00,67,00,72,00,61,00,6d,00,20,\
00,46,00,69,00,6c,00,65,00,73,00,20,00,28,00,78,00,38,00,36,00,29,00,5c,00,\
4e,00,6f,00,74,00,65,00,70,00,61,00,64,00,2b,00,2b,00,5c,00,6e,00,6f,00,74,\
00,65,00,70,00,61,00,64,00,2b,00,2b,00,2e,00,65,00,78,00,65,00,22,00,20,00,\
2f,00,70,00,20,00,22,00,25,00,31,00,22,00,00,00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\JSEFile\Shell\Edit\Command]
@=”C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe” “%1″

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\JSEFile\Shell\Print\Command]
@=”C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe” /p “%1″

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\JSFile\Shell\Edit\Command]
@=”C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe” “%1″

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\JSFile\Shell\Print\Command]
@=”C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe” /p “%1″

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\regfile\shell\edit\command]
@=hex(2):22,00,43,00,3a,00,5c,00,50,00,72,00,6f,00,67,00,72,00,61,00,6d,00,20,\
00,46,00,69,00,6c,00,65,00,73,00,20,00,28,00,78,00,38,00,36,00,29,00,5c,00,\
4e,00,6f,00,74,00,65,00,70,00,61,00,64,00,2b,00,2b,00,5c,00,6e,00,6f,00,74,\
00,65,00,70,00,61,00,64,00,2b,00,2b,00,2e,00,65,00,78,00,65,00,22,00,20,00,\
22,00,25,00,31,00,22,00,00,00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\regfile\shell\print\command]
@=hex(2):22,00,43,00,3a,00,5c,00,50,00,72,00,6f,00,67,00,72,00,61,00,6d,00,20,\
00,46,00,69,00,6c,00,65,00,73,00,20,00,28,00,78,00,38,00,36,00,29,00,5c,00,\
4e,00,6f,00,74,00,65,00,70,00,61,00,64,00,2b,00,2b,00,5c,00,6e,00,6f,00,74,\
00,65,00,70,00,61,00,64,00,2b,00,2b,00,2e,00,65,00,78,00,65,00,22,00,20,00,\
2f,00,70,00,20,00,22,00,25,00,31,00,22,00,00,00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Microsoft.PowerShellScript.1\Shell\Open\Command]
@=”C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe” “%1″

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Microsoft.PowerShellData.1\Shell\Open\Command]
@=”C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe” “%1″

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Microsoft.PowerShellModule.1\Shell\Open\Command]
@=”C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe” “%1″

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\scriptletfile\Shell\Open\command]
@=”C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe” “%1″

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\txtfile\shell\open\command]
@=hex(2):22,00,43,00,3a,00,5c,00,50,00,72,00,6f,00,67,00,72,00,61,00,6d,00,20,\
00,46,00,69,00,6c,00,65,00,73,00,20,00,28,00,78,00,38,00,36,00,29,00,5c,00,\
4e,00,6f,00,74,00,65,00,70,00,61,00,64,00,2b,00,2b,00,5c,00,6e,00,6f,00,74,\
00,65,00,70,00,61,00,64,00,2b,00,2b,00,2e,00,65,00,78,00,65,00,22,00,20,00,\
22,00,25,00,31,00,22,00,00,00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\txtfile\shell\print\command]
@=hex(2):22,00,43,00,3a,00,5c,00,50,00,72,00,6f,00,67,00,72,00,61,00,6d,00,20,\
00,46,00,69,00,6c,00,65,00,73,00,20,00,28,00,78,00,38,00,36,00,29,00,5c,00,\
4e,00,6f,00,74,00,65,00,70,00,61,00,64,00,2b,00,2b,00,5c,00,6e,00,6f,00,74,\
00,65,00,70,00,61,00,64,00,2b,00,2b,00,2e,00,65,00,78,00,65,00,22,00,20,00,\
2f,00,70,00,20,00,22,00,25,00,31,00,22,00,00,00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\txtfile\shell\printto\command]
@=hex(2):22,00,43,00,3a,00,5c,00,50,00,72,00,6f,00,67,00,72,00,61,00,6d,00,20,\
00,46,00,69,00,6c,00,65,00,73,00,20,00,28,00,78,00,38,00,36,00,29,00,5c,00,\
4e,00,6f,00,74,00,65,00,70,00,61,00,64,00,2b,00,2b,00,5c,00,6e,00,6f,00,74,\
00,65,00,70,00,61,00,64,00,2b,00,2b,00,2e,00,65,00,78,00,65,00,22,00,20,00,\
2f,00,70,00,74,00,20,00,22,00,25,00,31,00,22,00,20,00,22,00,25,00,32,00,22,\
00,20,00,22,00,25,00,33,00,22,00,20,00,22,00,25,00,34,00,22,00,00,00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\VBEFile\Shell\Edit\Command]
@=hex(2):22,00,43,00,3a,00,5c,00,50,00,72,00,6f,00,67,00,72,00,61,00,6d,00,20,\
00,46,00,69,00,6c,00,65,00,73,00,20,00,28,00,78,00,38,00,36,00,29,00,5c,00,\
4e,00,6f,00,74,00,65,00,70,00,61,00,64,00,2b,00,2b,00,5c,00,6e,00,6f,00,74,\
00,65,00,70,00,61,00,64,00,2b,00,2b,00,2e,00,65,00,78,00,65,00,22,00,20,00,\
22,00,25,00,31,00,22,00,00,00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\VBEFile\Shell\Print\Command]
@=hex(2):22,00,43,00,3a,00,5c,00,50,00,72,00,6f,00,67,00,72,00,61,00,6d,00,20,\
00,46,00,69,00,6c,00,65,00,73,00,20,00,28,00,78,00,38,00,36,00,29,00,5c,00,\
4e,00,6f,00,74,00,65,00,70,00,61,00,64,00,2b,00,2b,00,5c,00,6e,00,6f,00,74,\
00,65,00,70,00,61,00,64,00,2b,00,2b,00,2e,00,65,00,78,00,65,00,22,00,20,00,\
2f,00,70,00,20,00,22,00,25,00,31,00,22,00,00,00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\VBSFile\Shell\Edit\Command]
@=hex(2):22,00,43,00,3a,00,5c,00,50,00,72,00,6f,00,67,00,72,00,61,00,6d,00,20,\
00,46,00,69,00,6c,00,65,00,73,00,20,00,28,00,78,00,38,00,36,00,29,00,5c,00,\
4e,00,6f,00,74,00,65,00,70,00,61,00,64,00,2b,00,2b,00,5c,00,6e,00,6f,00,74,\
00,65,00,70,00,61,00,64,00,2b,00,2b,00,2e,00,65,00,78,00,65,00,22,00,20,00,\
22,00,25,00,31,00,22,00,00,00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\VBSFile\Shell\Print\Command]
@=hex(2):22,00,43,00,3a,00,5c,00,50,00,72,00,6f,00,67,00,72,00,61,00,6d,00,20,\
00,46,00,69,00,6c,00,65,00,73,00,20,00,28,00,78,00,38,00,36,00,29,00,5c,00,\
4e,00,6f,00,74,00,65,00,70,00,61,00,64,00,2b,00,2b,00,5c,00,6e,00,6f,00,74,\
00,65,00,70,00,61,00,64,00,2b,00,2b,00,2e,00,65,00,78,00,65,00,22,00,20,00,\
2f,00,70,00,20,00,22,00,25,00,31,00,22,00,00,00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Windows.XamlDocument\shell\edit\command]
@=hex(2):22,00,43,00,3a,00,5c,00,50,00,72,00,6f,00,67,00,72,00,61,00,6d,00,20,\
00,46,00,69,00,6c,00,65,00,73,00,20,00,28,00,78,00,38,00,36,00,29,00,5c,00,\
4e,00,6f,00,74,00,65,00,70,00,61,00,64,00,2b,00,2b,00,5c,00,6e,00,6f,00,74,\
00,65,00,70,00,61,00,64,00,2b,00,2b,00,2e,00,65,00,78,00,65,00,22,00,20,00,\
22,00,25,00,31,00,22,00,00,00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Windows.Xbap\shell\edit\command]
@=hex(2):22,00,43,00,3a,00,5c,00,50,00,72,00,6f,00,67,00,72,00,61,00,6d,00,20,\
00,46,00,69,00,6c,00,65,00,73,00,20,00,28,00,78,00,38,00,36,00,29,00,5c,00,\
4e,00,6f,00,74,00,65,00,70,00,61,00,64,00,2b,00,2b,00,5c,00,6e,00,6f,00,74,\
00,65,00,70,00,61,00,64,00,2b,00,2b,00,2e,00,65,00,78,00,65,00,22,00,20,00,\
22,00,25,00,31,00,22,00,00,00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Windows.CompositeFont\shell\open\command]
@=hex(2):22,00,43,00,3a,00,5c,00,50,00,72,00,6f,00,67,00,72,00,61,00,6d,00,20,\
00,46,00,69,00,6c,00,65,00,73,00,20,00,28,00,78,00,38,00,36,00,29,00,5c,00,\
4e,00,6f,00,74,00,65,00,70,00,61,00,64,00,2b,00,2b,00,5c,00,6e,00,6f,00,74,\
00,65,00,70,00,61,00,64,00,2b,00,2b,00,2e,00,65,00,78,00,65,00,22,00,20,00,\
22,00,25,00,31,00,22,00,00,00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\WSFFile\Shell\Edit\Command]
@=hex(2):22,00,43,00,3a,00,5c,00,50,00,72,00,6f,00,67,00,72,00,61,00,6d,00,20,\
00,46,00,69,00,6c,00,65,00,73,00,20,00,28,00,78,00,38,00,36,00,29,00,5c,00,\
4e,00,6f,00,74,00,65,00,70,00,61,00,64,00,2b,00,2b,00,5c,00,6e,00,6f,00,74,\
00,65,00,70,00,61,00,64,00,2b,00,2b,00,2e,00,65,00,78,00,65,00,22,00,20,00,\
22,00,25,00,31,00,22,00,00,00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\WSFFile\Shell\Print\Command]
@=hex(2):22,00,43,00,3a,00,5c,00,50,00,72,00,6f,00,67,00,72,00,61,00,6d,00,20,\
00,46,00,69,00,6c,00,65,00,73,00,20,00,28,00,78,00,38,00,36,00,29,00,5c,00,\
4e,00,6f,00,74,00,65,00,70,00,61,00,64,00,2b,00,2b,00,5c,00,6e,00,6f,00,74,\
00,65,00,70,00,61,00,64,00,2b,00,2b,00,2e,00,65,00,78,00,65,00,22,00,20,00,\
2f,00,70,00,20,00,22,00,25,00,31,00,22,00,00,00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\zapfile\shell\open\command]
@=hex(2):22,00,43,00,3a,00,5c,00,50,00,72,00,6f,00,67,00,72,00,61,00,6d,00,20,\
00,46,00,69,00,6c,00,65,00,73,00,20,00,28,00,78,00,38,00,36,00,29,00,5c,00,\
4e,00,6f,00,74,00,65,00,70,00,61,00,64,00,2b,00,2b,00,5c,00,6e,00,6f,00,74,\
00,65,00,70,00,61,00,64,00,2b,00,2b,00,2e,00,65,00,78,00,65,00,22,00,20,00,\
22,00,25,00,31,00,22,00,00,00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\zapfile\shell\print\command]
@=hex(2):22,00,43,00,3a,00,5c,00,50,00,72,00,6f,00,67,00,72,00,61,00,6d,00,20,\
00,46,00,69,00,6c,00,65,00,73,00,20,00,28,00,78,00,38,00,36,00,29,00,5c,00,\
4e,00,6f,00,74,00,65,00,70,00,61,00,64,00,2b,00,2b,00,5c,00,6e,00,6f,00,74,\
00,65,00,70,00,61,00,64,00,2b,00,2b,00,2e,00,65,00,78,00,65,00,22,00,20,00,\
2f,00,70,00,20,00,22,00,25,00,31,00,22,00,00,00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\zapfile\shell\printto\command]
@=hex(2):22,00,43,00,3a,00,5c,00,50,00,72,00,6f,00,67,00,72,00,61,00,6d,00,20,\
00,46,00,69,00,6c,00,65,00,73,00,20,00,28,00,78,00,38,00,36,00,29,00,5c,00,\
4e,00,6f,00,74,00,65,00,70,00,61,00,64,00,2b,00,2b,00,5c,00,6e,00,6f,00,74,\
00,65,00,70,00,61,00,64,00,2b,00,2b,00,2e,00,65,00,78,00,65,00,22,00,20,00,\
2f,00,70,00,74,00,20,00,22,00,25,00,31,00,22,00,20,00,22,00,25,00,32,00,22,\
00,20,00,22,00,25,00,33,00,22,00,20,00,22,00,25,00,34,00,22,00,00,00
```

Comment: I also wanted a solution without using notepad++ but rather Windows, since I know its a problem with the registry. I need this option for all files (not just SQL etc). So I agree that the upvoted solutions are not the right ones. I verified that the hex is actually just "notepad++". Haven't tested by applying the patch though.

Comment: It only works if Notepad++ has been installed to `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe"` (which is the default), otherwise it will fail. There is no real need to write these commands as hexadecimal strings, plain text is accepted too with appropriate escapings. It's not too complicated to convert these hexadecimal texts to string with online tools like this: http://codebeautify.org/hex-string-converter. BTW the first hexadecimal text can be decoded to `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe" "%1"`.

Comment: `I don't understand the upvotes and the selection of the right answer. None of these answers are answering the question`, perhaps in the past it didn't work but now doing as the accepted answer says, it will bind the files to be opened by default on notepad++.

Comment: Windows 7 Enterprise works as a charm. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

As an alternative, you can also replace notepad.exe with notepad++.exe (or notepad2.exe or another editor).

Take a look at this gist to get an idea on how to do it: https://gist.github.com/amarraja/3938304

Comment: This works too: http://www.binaryfortress.com/NotepadReplacer/Download/

Answer (score 3):

The most direct route I've found is tell Windows to use Notepad++ (or Notepad2 or...) instead of the system default Notepad.exe by leveraging *Image File Execution*. It's safer (and easier!) than replacing system files or messing about with multiple registry entries.

- [set "Image File Execution Options" will always open the named exe file as default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2984846/set-image-file-execution-options-will-always-open-the-named-exe-file-as-defaul)

Other Sources:

- [Replace Notepad with Notepad2 (or Notepad++)](https://serverfault.com/questions/29384/replace-notepad-with-notepad2-or-notepad)
- [Inside 'Image File Execution Options' debugging](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/greggm/archive/2005/02/21/377663.aspx)