# How to make notepad++ the default editor for a Windows batch file?

Tags: windows, notepad++

In Windows, if you right-click a `.bat` file, there's an "Edit" option, which opens the .bat file with `notepad`. How do I make Windows use `Notepad++` instead?

Note that this is different from the question [How do I set Notepad++ as the default editor?](https://superuser.com/q/474079/91054). In that question, user asks for a way to make `Notepad++` the default opener for specific file types. This is not what I want here, since I expect that double-clicking on `.bat` files executes them.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Change the program associated to the "Edit" verb for batch files:

- Run RegEdit (as admin)
- Navigate to `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\batfile\shell\edit\command`.
- Modify the Default and change Value Data from `%SystemRoot%\System32\NOTEPAD.EXE %1` to  `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe" "%1"`
- Close RegEdit.
- Right-click -> "Edit" should now open batch files in NotePad++.

*Note:* You may have to adjust your path to Notepad++.exe if it resides in a different folder on your system.

*Also note:* This is a system-wide change.

Comment: @MarkDuncan That's not really an alternative way to assign Notepad++ to the R-Click -> Edit menu entry. ;)

Comment: @Techie007 - No it's a quick and easy way without the need to rewrite any registry entries. I came here looking for the same solution(edit with another program) but then realised drag and drop would be sufficient.

Comment: Used to do this, but it's not working after win8. Is there any way to do this in win8 / win10 ?  Btw I'm using notepad2.  In win8/win10, it will show "windows can't open this type of file (.cmd / .bat)"

Comment: @POW Just did it in Win 10. Working correctly, no errors.

Comment: Never mind. Not working for Sublime Text 3. Sublime tries to open the folder and the file, presents it like it's a blank document, and asks you to save when you try to close it.

Comment: I had to put quotation marks around `%1` to make it work with file paths with spaces: `"%1"`

Comment: In 2022, notepad++ installs at `C:\Program Files\Notepad++\notepad++.exe`

Answer (score 2):

If there are spaces in the filename being edited then double-quotes (`"`) can be used to surround the argument. For example:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe" "%1"
```