# Set Notepad++ as the default EDIT program for '.txt' files?

Tags: windows-10, notepad++, editing, right-click

Searching all over, I could **not** get Windows 10 file manager to open Notepad++ on the **right-click > Edit** option.  There are quite a few answers on how to get the **right-click > Open**, and also **double-click** on the ".txt" file. So no problems there.

(Please note:  This is NOT the same as right-click>Edit on .bat files.  That problem has been covered here: [How to make notepad++ the default editor for a Windows batch file?](https://superuser.com/questions/728152/how-to-make-notepad-the-default-editor-for-a-windows-batch-file)  )

But that left me scratching, because sometimes I use the **right-click>Edit** action, and Windows 10 file Explorer always opened NOTEPAD.

Comment: You need to delete your first question. Double click and Open can be changed by users via the Open With menu item.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I fixed it:

RegEdit:  open:  `Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\.txt`

Add the following three key values:  shell, edit, command
so you have this address:
`Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\.txt\shell\edit\command`
With `command` selected in the left pane, you see:
   `(Default)   REG_SZ`  on the right.

Right click on `(Default)`, select `Modify...` then add this `Value data:`

`"C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe" "%1"`

Close RegEdit.

Now I can **right-click > Edit** any ".txt" file and it opens Notepad++.